# Amazon S3 redundancy over Availability Zones vs. over Regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, high-availability

This [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/architecting-for-high-availability-on-amazon-s3/#:~:text=Amazon%20S3%20maintains%20redundancy%20even%20within%20one%20of,can%20still%20access%20their%20data%20with%20no%20downtime](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/architecting-for-high-availability-on-amazon-s3/#:%7E:text=Amazon%20S3%20maintains%20redundancy%20even%20within%20one%20of,can%20still%20access%20their%20data%20with%20no%20downtime) states the following:

> Amazon S3 storage classes replicate their data on more than three
> Availability Zone (except for S3 One Zone-Infrequent Access).

What's the point of this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/large-scale-disaster-recovery-using-aws-regions/ stating:

> S3 snapshots:  We rely on the cross s3 sync and this works like a
> charm. We are able to copy the data from our primary to the DR region
> within a matter of few minutes.

The latter seem superfluous now and is from 2017, so may be it is out-dated? Or is it the thrust that we should also be be placing Amazon S3 copies over over Regions? I see no such need as the AZ's within a Region are physically separated from each other. What am I missing?

Comment: @smac2020  maybe u can offer an insight? I guess it's just an extra level of safety?

Comment: Are you referring to my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 buckets are region specific. When you create a new bucket you need to select the target region for that bucket.

For DR reasons, you can keep backups in another region. Should the primary region fail in a way that the entire region is affected, then you could restore in the backup region.

Your DR strategy will depend on your use case, and your needs for returning services back to normal in case of region wide failure.

For example, let's say you rely on ec2/ebs to operate your service and those services suffer region wide outage for 5 hours. In order to recover your service you would need to move to a region where the resources are available. Assuming you need S3 data for operational processing you would want to have that data ready in the Target recovery region.

Comment: OK, I thought a whole region failure would be unlikely.

Comment: It's rare, but it has happened. The article you referred to mentions an outage due to region wide floods.

Comment: Some good discussion on the subject https://amp.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/2oia0q/does_anybody_know_the_incidence_of_aws_regionwide/

Answer (score 1):

Storing in multiple AZs in a region does not guarantee safety in case of entire region failure.This is applicable for all regional services. The article you shared indeed mentions this so it is not irrelevant.

> The service that runs in HA is handled by hosts running in different
> availability zones but in the same geographical region. This approach,
> however, does not guarantee that our business will be up and running
> in case the entire region goes down

Comment: But when could that occur? Seems unlike a Region would go down?

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: Chances of entire region going down are less but you are expected to design your system to tolerate it if it ever happens. Of course you may choose not to if your RTO/RPO permits you that. Here is  some interesting read https://www.datacenterknowledge.com/amazon/aws-says-it-s-never-seen-whole-data-center-go-down